# Calculate Average of Numbers in between each other C++

Tags: c++, windows

Im trying to retrieve values from the user and then use those values to print out the numbers in between them. The numbers have to fall into certain parameters. I need to find the average of the numbers in between the two user inputs but I have no idea how to get those. I can calculate the sum but I cannot figure out how to divide by the number of numbers in the sequence.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
//retrieves box dimensions 
int boxHeight;

cout << "Enter a box height (between 3 and 10):";
cin >> boxHeight;
while (boxHeight < 3 || boxHeight > 10)
{
    cout << "That number is out of bounds. Try again:";
    cin >> boxHeight;
}
//retrieves width
int boxWidth;
cout << "Enter a box width (between 6 and 20 and greater than box height):";
cin >> boxWidth;
while (boxWidth < 6 || boxWidth > 20 || boxWidth <= boxHeight)
{
    cout << "That number is out of bounds. Try again:";
    cin >> boxWidth;
}

//output numbers between height and width
cout << "The numbers Between " << boxHeight << " and " << boxWidth << " are: " "\n";
double sum = 0;
while (boxHeight <= boxWidth)
{
    //adds the sum
    double x = boxHeight;
    cout << boxHeight << " ";
    boxHeight++;
    sum += x;


}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Overall, what you have looks reasonable. I think you may have an off-by-one error, but other than that all I would add is another variable to keep track of the number of numbers summed so I could get the average from the sum. You're almost there.

Comment: Unless I've missed something the average is always going to be` (boxHeight + boxWidth)/2`. Beware that if the sum is odd the result will be truncated.

Comment: You can count how many numbers in the sequence by creating a int variable outside the last while loop, then increment it by one each time you do a `sum += x'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much I can understand, you want to find average instead of sum. It's easy, just create another variable to track number of times you have added to sum and then divide sum by that number

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
//retrieves box dimensions 
int boxHeight;

cout << "Enter a box height (between 3 and 10):";
cin >> boxHeight;
while (boxHeight < 3 || boxHeight > 10)
{
    cout << "That number is out of bounds. Try again:";
    cin >> boxHeight;
}
//retrieves width
int boxWidth;
cout << "Enter a box width (between 6 and 20 and greater than box height):";
cin >> boxWidth;
while (boxWidth < 6 || boxWidth > 20 || boxWidth <= boxHeight)
{
    cout << "That number is out of bounds. Try again:";
    cin >> boxWidth;
}

//output numbers between height and width
cout << "The numbers Between " << boxHeight << " and " << boxWidth << " are: " "\n";
double sum = 0;
unsigned int num = 0;    //to track number of additions
while (boxHeight <= boxWidth)
{
    //adds the sum
    double x = boxHeight;
    cout << boxHeight << " ";
    boxHeight++;
    sum += x;
    num++;
}

sum /= num;    //divide to find average
return 0;
}
```